# Rename [fire-emblem-echos-shadows-valentia] -> [fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Someone decided to go and extend [fire-emblem-echoes-sov](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-echoes-sov) into [fire-emblem-echos-shadows-valentia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-echos-shadows-valentia), which has one glaring issue -- "echoes" is spelled incorrectly. Could a moderator go and rename this tag?

Comment: Whoops! My bad. Do you want me to just go ahead and manually rename it, or get a mod involved?

Comment: @Thunderforge I'm not sure if you can since the two tags would be so similar. Plus, a moderator can just rename the tag itself and change them all at once without spamming the front page with the affected posts.

Comment: @Vemonus - if you are only adding (or removing) a dash then the system will stop you from creating the new tag. Otherwise it's fair game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the typo! Since the front page was already spammed with the questions, I went ahead and just edited them all again to have the correct tag name. That way, we can give our busy mods a break!

I also submitted a tag wiki for [fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia) that is waiting for approval.

Comment: In the future, please try not to do quite so many edits in a row - although I appreciate this was a bit of a special case, it did kinda push new stuff off the front page. :) (Although thanks for thinking of us busy mods and getting some stuff done, we appreciate the help!)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. When I've done it before, it's been for tags that only had 5 or so questions that need to be retagged. This was the largest I did, and I planned to take a break and not retag any more until well after they were all pushed off the front page. I'll definitely be saving the big ones for [tag-rename-request] meta topics, which hopefully you all will have time to get to.